# Как убрать полосы прокрутки до срабатывания функции с пом. jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Мне нужно запретить прокрутку браузера, до тех пор, пока слайдер не переключится на последний слайд. Как это сделать, и возможно ли это вообще? Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        let qtySlides = $('.slider>div').length-1;
            let slider=$('.slider').slick({
                dots: true,
                speed: 300,
                autoplay: true,
                autoplaySpeed: 3000,
                infinite: false
            });
            slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
                if( qtySlides === slider.slick('slickCurrentSlide') ){
                    slider.slickSetOption("autoplay",false,false)
                };
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Точно не понимаю, когда у вас отображается последний слайд в слайдере. Но, чтобы запретить/разрешить скроллинг можно использовать следующий код:

```js
var keys = { //коды клавиш, по которым запрещено скроллить.
  37: 1,
  38: 1,
  39: 1,
  40: 1,
  32: 1
};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
}

function disableScroll() {
  window.onwheel = preventDefault;
  window.ontouchmove = preventDefault;
  document.onkeydown = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
  document.getElementById('block').innerHTML = 'Теперь можно скроллить!';
  window.onwheel = null;
  window.ontouchmove = null;
  document.onkeydown = null;
}

//вызов
disableScroll();
setTimeout(enableScroll, 3000);
```

```css
#block {
  height: 5000px;
  background-color: #b7b7ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">Тут контент</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Сам код
window.blockScroll = false;

$(window).on("scroll",function(){
  if(window.blockScroll !== false){
    $(this).scrollTop(window.blockScroll);
    return false;
  }
});



// Это для демки
$("body").on("click", ".onOff", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var textBtn = (window.blockScroll !== false) ? "LOCK SCROLL" : "UNLOCK SCROLL";
  $(this).text(textBtn);
 window.blockScroll = (window.blockScroll !== false) ? false : $(window).scrollTop(); // revers
})
```

```css
body{
max-height:300px;
overflow:scroll;
}
.onOff{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
 <li>Demo Demo</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="onOff">LOCK SCROLL</a>
```